# what / which back-end an appstore or play market app is using?

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, backend

How can one find out which or what an app is using as a back-end server? 
Assume you are making an app and you are using Parse.com as your back-end server. You made an app and go published it to the appstore. Later, what are the odds for some one else to find out what did you use as a back-end server? Can she/he find out that you used Parse.com ?
What are the odds for an iOS app and Android playmarket app ?

Comment: Yes one can find out if developer decompile app and view it in case of android.

Comment: i have my own reasons.

Comment: can a user decompile app that he/she downloaded from play market ?

Comment: It would be possible if one look at the network traffic. Most of the wireless routers available today can log the traffic. So, if you want to find out it's quite easy.

Comment: yes one can decompile app from play market. @IamMashed

Comment: They could use Charles (others are available) to track their phones web calls and see the url information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply see what networks calls are being made by the app. No need to decompile or anything like that. Simply log network calls on your home network. Your Wifi router might do this or you could setup a proxy server that logs all requests.